# File size limit iOS (5.1+)

Tags: ios

The iOS app I'm working on handles very large files (largest being 2.7 gig in size), and some sqlite tables,  after downloading the large I'm getting console messages like this one :

```
Aug 24 14:50:28 unknown TheAppName[1407] <Warning>: Error opening database: 14 unable to open database file
```

Also other issues that happen, loading a view (which has already been loaded and presented) will cause a crash saying "nib cannot be located".

The app can run without the large file just fine, but it is very useful to have.  The question I have is this : Is the large file causing some sort of memory issue, or is there some sort of limit that iOS places on files?  I've looked around at other places and I've been unable to find anything specific to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work in the Simulator or do you also have the same issue there?

I suggest you run your app using Instruments with the ObjectAlloc tool. Its likely you have some leaks in the way you are managing the download. Or, is there free space on the device for this file?

Others have had success with downloading huge files as long as sufficient space exists on the flash. You can test for this - there are a few functions floating around that tell you how to determine free disk space.

Another idea: write your file to the disk with the "F_NOCACHE" (fcntl) flag set on the file descriptor. This will cause the writes to bypass the "uniform buffer queue", which is used to cache disk blocks and for other memory uses, and will greatly reduce stress on the system itself.

Comment: The app works perfectly in the simulator, and the device has enough space for the file.

Comment: Fine - so look at the memory usage while downloading. The Simulator has gobs of memory and won't run out even if you leak. The real device will. Also, that nocache flag can really help reduce pressure on the system as I indicated. There is NO way to measure or observe the UBC (unified buffer cache) - I talked to even iOS/OSX system dev managers at WWDC about this and no way to do it (now). I have had my own problems with putting too much pressure on UBC.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have time right now to test it, so Monday I'll test and check to see if this worked.

Comment: NP - have a nice weekend! Do both though - Instruments check (use Simulator, should be the same).

Answer (score -1):

An iOS app's max size limit is 2GB, this is limit is causing all the errors and is why your app is crashing. I would recommend you upload your large size files to a file hosting site and stream them into the app when you need them.

Comment: Do you happen to have any reference of that? I looked through apple's documentation and wasn't able to find that.

Comment: Right - an app is 32 bits. But files have a 64bit length, so can obviously be much larger

Comment: Is located [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf)

Comment: It is on page 167 of the iTunes Connect Developer's Guide.

Comment: Right - page 214 of the current guide (the one linked above). To quote "iOS apps can be as large as 2 GB" - so the App is limited to that size, but a file it creates is limited only but the amount of free space or 64bits, which ever happens first :-)

Comment: The app is not creating the file, the file is part of the app, therefore creating the crash.